# Create a pointer to a specific location

Tags: memory, variables, pointers, assembly, nasm

I need a pointer to location which is always the same. So, how can I create a pointer to.. lets say memory address 0x20 and store it in some way to be able to access it later.
Note:
I do NOT want to store the result, but the actual pointer to the memory address (since I want to point to the beginning of an array).

Thanks in advance.

--

I think I have fixed it now. I use bios interrupt 0x15 to get a memory map. Every interrupt returns 1 entry and you provide a pointer in es:di to a place where the bios can store it. I let the bios build it up from 050h:0h. I needed a pointer to 0x50:0x0 (0x500 linear) to use the map later. I still have to test, but I did the following:

```
    mov ax, 0x50
    mov es, ax
    xor di, di

    shl ax, 4
    add ax, di
    mov [mmr], ax
```

And mmr is declared this way:

```
mmr:
    dw 0 ; pointer to the first entry
    db 0 ;entry count
    db 24 ; entry size
```

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is just a memory address and a memory address is just a number. Assembly is not a typed language so there is no difference.

Also assembly doesn't really have variables. It has registers and memory locations, both of which can be used for storing values, including addresses/pointers.

So basically there are many variants of the x86 `MOV` instruction that can store a pointer such as `0x20` in an address or a register. You certainly want to think about whether you're doing 32-bit or 64-bit x86 assembly though (or 16-bit or even 8-bit for that matter).

Comment: It is in 16-bit real mode.

So if I understand you right, you create a pointer to linear address 0x20 when you do

mov eax, 20H

Comment: I'm not fluent in x86, most of my assembly was in Z80 and Motorola 680x0 years ago but yes you are putting the "value" 0x20 into the register eax. You're not really doing anything pointerish with it just by storing it though. Dereferencing it or taking an offset from it would be typical pointer operations. Also `EAX` is a 32-bit register if I recall correctly but I never really understood the concepts such as "real mode".

Answer (score 2):

x86:

suppose you have an array called `list`

```
mov bx, offset list
```

now, in the bx register you will have a pointer to the first memory location of `list`

to refer to the data in the memory location you would use `[bx]`

---

here's an brief example using intel syntax:

```
;declare list in .data
list dw 0123h

;move 01h from memory to ax register (16-bit)
mov bx, offset list
mov al, [bx] ; al = 23h
```

If you want to use the pointer later you can do this:

`push bx` then `pop bx` when you want to use it

or

`mov point, bx ; declared in mmr`